# World Wind Objects Getting Cut Off by the Terrains in the Map

Tags: worldwind

So I'm working on this project that uses World Wind, and it has world wind objects (the white lines) going from one object to another in different parts of the map.
My problem is when they hit a terrain, they get cut off instead of going through it. Any idea how to fix this? I attached the image through this link to show what I mean.
[World Wind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITy6l.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most World Wind renderables have an altitudeMode that can be set. For example, I am using a [Path](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.2/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/render/Path.html) to draw a line from one point to another. I can do `path.setAltitudeMode(WorldWind.CLAMP_TO_GROUND)`. This will force the line to follow the terrain. Different modes can be set depending how you want to show the renderable. [This](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/2.0/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/render/PointPlacemark.html#setAltitudeMode(int)) explains how each mode will render.